# How can I hide *.extension~ files by using auto hide plugin?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

I have successfully hidden undo files by using this auto hide plugin, but I could not hide any *.extension~ files.

suppose I created a.txt

Now there are two files shown in windows explorer

- a.txt
- **a.txt~**
- a.txt.un~ (Hidden)

**I want to hide a.txt~ on save.**

How can I do that?

I think I need to use the

**p pattern option for this**

- **Auto hide plugin**

  `*g:autohide_types* (default "suv")
    b = backup files (currently doesn't work with 'backupdir') 
   s = swap files
    u = undo files
    v = viminfo 
   p = files matching pattern`

  - My vimrc file

> ```
> source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
>
>     set diffexpr=MyDiff()
>     function MyDiff()
>       let opt = '-a --binary '
>       if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
>       if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
>       let arg1 = v:fname_in
>       if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
>       let arg1 = substitute(arg1, '!', '\!', 'g')
>       let arg2 = v:fname_new
>       if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
>       let arg2 = substitute(arg2, '!', '\!', 'g')
>       let arg3 = v:fname_out
>       if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
>       let arg3 = substitute(arg3, '!', '\!', 'g')
>       if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
>         if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
>           if empty(&shellxquote)
>             let l:shxq_sav = ''
>             set shellxquote&
>           endif
>           let cmd = '"' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
>         else
>           let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
>         endif
>       else
>         let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
>       endif
>       let cmd = substitute(cmd, '!', '\!', 'g')
>       silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3
>       if exists('l:shxq_sav')
>         let &shellxquote=l:shxq_sav
>       endif
>     endfunction
>
>
>    let g:autohide_file_list='suvb'
> ```

What I have tried

- [Hide Vim backups (*~) in Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885725/hide-vim-backups-in-windows-explorer/43663493#comment100191400_43663493%20-)
- [autohide : Set 'hidden' attribute on swap files and the like in Windows](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4505)

Comment: `autohide_types` is a global variable, it should be declared like this `let g:autohide_types='b'`. But if you want to add type to existing list it should be like this `let g:autohide_types+='b'`

Comment: @AlexKroll string concatenation is `.`, so `let g:autohide_types.='b'`. Please post answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: I have edited my question @D.BenKnoble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autohide_types` is a global variable, it should be declared like this

`let g:autohide_types='b'`

But if you want to add type to existing list it should be like this

`let g:autohide_types.='b'`

Unfortunetly this plugin works only with glob patterns and does not works with regexp. But it has public function `Autohide_DoHide({file})`. So workaround

- [You must have installed  auto hide plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4505)
- Then You should add this line to vimrc file

`autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost * silent call Autohide_DoHide(expand('%:p').'~')`

Comment: I added let g:autohide_types.='b'. vim says Error detected while processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc:

line   38:

E121: Undefined variable: g:autohide_types

Comment: Because variable is not defined. For first time  `let g:autohide_types='b'` and then `let g:autohide_types.='u'` But it strange, are you sure that `autohide` plugin is loaded?

Comment: How can I chech that? @AlexKroll

Comment: Oh, i've checked plugin sources. You should declare variable by yourself.

Comment: It does not hide a.txt~ file @alexKroll

Comment: It does not hide *.*~ files. I can achieve that by autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost * silent ! attrib +h *.*~ . But I want to do this by auto hide plugin @AlexKroll

Comment: Unfortunetly this plugin works only with glob patterns and does not works with regexp. But it has public function `Autohide_DoHide({file})`. So `autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *~ silent call Autohide_DoHide(expand('%'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95565/discussion-between-aman-and-alex-kroll).